# Attempt to read property "needs_password" on null

Tags: laravel

I created a password initial with email notification, now the problem here is when i click the link in the email i got an error. it says attempt to read property on null

this is my code by the way.

in my users table i add the

```
$table->boolean('needs_password')->default(false);
```

the User Model

```
    protected $table = 'users';
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'rec_id',
    'email',
    'join_date',
    'phone_number',
    'status',
    'role_name',
    'avatar',
    'needs_password',
    'password',
];
```

and my user controller after the admin create a user

```
        $url = URL::signedRoute('password-redirect');
        $pass  = Str::random(30);
        $image = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('/assets/images/'), $image);

        $user = new User;
        $user->name             = $request->name;
        $user->email            = $request->email;
        $user->join_date        = $todayDate;
        $user->role_name        = $request->role_name;
        $user->status           = $request->status;
        $user->avatar           = $image;
        $user->password         = $pass;
        $user->save();
        DB::commit();            
        Mail::send('auth.mail', [ 'url' => $url], function($message) use ($request) {
            $message->from('noreply@taskproph.com');
            $message->to($request->email);
            $message->subject('Reset Password Notification');
        });
```

in my password controller

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('signed');
    $this->middleware('needs_password');
}

public function create(User $user)
{
    return view('auth.mail');
}
```

in my need_password middleware

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
   $user = $request->route('users');

   if ($user->needs_password) {
    
    return $next($request);

   }

   abort(400);
}
```

in my route

```
Route::controller(PasswordController::class)->group(function () {
Route::get('/password-redirect', 'create')->middleware('signed','needPass')->name('password-redirect');
Route::post('/create-password', 'store')->middleware('needPass')->name('create-password');
```

});

Comment: "it says attempt to read property on null" It says more than that. Which property, and which line of code? I'm **guessing** it's in your middleware, because `$request->route('users')` will be null in both of your routes, because neither route has a "users" param in it.

Comment: the line of code is in the need_password middleware 

if($user->needs_password)

Comment: Then my theory is correct. `$user` is null there for both of these routes. Your code can't work as-is, and the logic doesn't really make sense to me anyways; you don't want to throw a 400 error if the user doesn't have a password when they're on the "create-password" route, right? They'd never be able to set one!

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $request->route('users');

if ($user->needs_password) {
```

These lines will fail in both of your routes, because the routes don't **have** a route parameter called "users". `$user` is always null for them. You're likely going to want to use `$request->user()` instead, and you're going to potentially want to handle cases where there's no currently logged-in user as well by checking that `$request->user()` returns something.

You've also got a logic error - your middleware (if it worked) is throwing an error 400 if the user has no password, but you're applying it to the `create-password` route. This means the user can't set a password!

These are probably the two routes that **shouldn't** have the `needPass` middleware applied.

Comment: my plan is to create an create a password, where after the admin creating a user, a user will received an email notification with signUrls, and then when the user click the link the system will check if the user specified in the URL still needs to choose a password. If they already have chosen a password (needs_password = false), then you can return an error message, or redirect somewhere with a flash message saying the URL has expired or something.